# Python - save color from bar chart similar to get_color() for line charts

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to save the color of a bar plot in a variable to be used to set tick and label colors for an axis?  I know this is possible using get_color() for line plots, but it does not work for bar plots.

```
style_format='seaborn'
mpl.style.use(style_format)

fig, ax_1 = plt.subplots()
ax_2 = ax_1.twinx()
ax_2.grid(None)
plot_1, = ax_1.errorbar(df['date'].tolist(), ptt['avg'].tolist(), 
                         yerr=df['std'].tolist(), fmt='-o')
bar_1 = ax_2.bar(df['date'].tolist(), df['count'].tolist(), alpha=0.25)

plot_1_color = plot_1.get_color()
#this is where the code breaks. have tried get_facecolor() as well
bar_1_color = bar_1.get_color()

ax_1.yaxis.label.set_color(plot_1_color)
ax_2.yaxis.label.set_color(bar_1_color)
```

I have not found a way to do this in either the matplotlib documentation or anywhere else.  Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The relevant documention for the return of the call to `ax.bar` (a `BarContainer`) can be found here: https://matplotlib.org/api/container_api.html#matplotlib.container.BarContainer.

Additionally, you need not call `.tolist()` on your series objects. You can simply pass them as-is.

Comment: You may have several bars, and those bars do not necessarily have the same color. So you need to pick one bar and use its color, `bar_1[0].get_facecolor()`.

Comment: thanks. I get errors when i remove .tolist() calls, which was why i initially added that. appreciate the responses.